# How to improve the usage of lock_keys in Perl?

Tags: perl, hash

I'm using `Hash::Util`'s `lock_keys` to die whenever trying to access a non-existing key in a hash.

1. Sometimes my hashes are deep (hash
   of hashes of hashes...). Is there a 
   quick method to lock them all at once?
2. Is it possible to control the
       default message upon failure (i.e.
       add a Dump of the hash in which the key wasn't found)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. [`lock_hash_recurse`](http://p3rl.org/Hash::Util#lock_hash_recurse)
2. Catch the exception, then dump as you wish and rethrow.

---

```
use Try::Tiny;
try {
    $hash{key} = 123; # illegal modification
} catch {
    use DDS; DumpLex \%hash;
    die $_;
}
```

Comment: You would have to wrap every hash lookup, that may not be feasible.

Comment: `use Hash::Util qw(lock_hash_recurse unlock_hash_recurse)` gives me `"lock_hash_recurse" is not exported by the Hash::Util module "unlock_hash_recurse" is not exported by the Hash::Util module` ???

Comment: The function is not exportable. Say the full name: `Hash::Util::lock_hash_recurse …`

Comment: I just replaced some `lock_keys` with `lock_hash_recurse` and now I get errors: `Use of uninitialized value in string eq at /usr/lib/perl/5.10/Hash/Util.pm line 153.`

Comment: [Open a new question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask), and there provide the data you work with.

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3727619/how-do-i-use-lock-hash-recurse-in-perl

Answer (score 1):

Question 2 is possible, but you are at the whims of the Hash::Util author(s):

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict;
use warnings;

use Hash::Util qw/lock_keys/;

$SIG{__DIE__} = sub {
    my $message = shift;
    return unless my ($key, $file, $line) = $message =~ m{
        Attempt [ ] to [ ] access [ ] disallowed [ ] key [ ] '(.*?)'
        [ ] in [ ] a [ ] restricted [ ] hash [ ] at [ ] (.*?) [ ]
        line [ ] (.*?).
    }x;
    die "$key doesn't exist at $file line $line.\n";
};

my %h = map { $_ => undef } "a" .. "z";
lock_keys %h;

my $s = $h{4};
```